# Obscure JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript

...obscure to me, anyway. Can anyone tell me what this means? I have various bits of code that look like this:

```
node[foo](bar, function() { 
   ...do something to 'node'
});
```

'node' is a single DOM node. 'foo' and 'bar' are both strings, though the code sets 'bar' to a boolean occasionally. The 'do something' code is occasionally executed, but only (I think) if 'bar' is `true`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node` apparently has a property, of which the name is contained in `foo`. The property contains (or refers to) a function. This function is called with the value of `bar` and a callback function as its parameters.

Since objects can have extra properties assigned, a JavaScript library might set this 'foo' property of a node, even though it's not a native property of a DOM node. I believe JQuery uses this concept quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out that 'foo' was actually a jQuery function name.